# What GIS-related services have been affected by past U.S. government shutdown?

Tags: data, united-states

I noticed [data.gov](http://data.gov), the US government's open data (including GIS) clearinghouse, was down, reading the following message:

> Due to the lapse in federal government funding, this website is not
>   available. We sincerely regret this inconvenience.
>
> For information about available government services, visit USA.gov.

Similarly, [usgs.gov](http://www.usgs.gov/) is down, with only critical USGS websites available:

> - Ecosystems
>
>   - [Disease Maps](http://diseasemaps.usgs.gov/)
> - Natural Hazards
>
>   - [USGS coastal erosion hazards information](http://coastal.er.usgs.gov/hurricanes/erosionhazards/)
>   - [USGS earthquake information](http://earthquake.usgs.gov/)
>   - [USGS emergency operations portal](http://hdds.usgs.gov/EO/)
>   - [USGS information on geomagnetic activity](http://geomag.usgs.gov/)
>   - [USGS landslide information](http://landslides.usgs.gov/)
>   - [USGS volcano information](http://volcanoes.usgs.gov/)
> - [Water](http://water.usgs.gov/)

Presumably this is only a temporary outage. Are there any other services that have been affected, and any permanently?

**Update:** Now that the US government has reopened, all of the sites linked so far in this thread appear to be back up.

Comment: Given this is a changing event, does this really belong here?

Comment: I suppose not, technically, but in extenuating circumstances I suggest we keep it open until the shutdown is un-shutdown... :)

Comment: The Census Bureau is also not accessible, including American Factfinder

Comment: While the government may be back soon, I think its valuable to take stock of what government geographic services were lost. +1 from me...

Comment: Now that the shutdown is over this question can be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like USDA is down:

http://datagateway.nrcs.usda.gov/

Their message reads:

*Site is Temporarily Unavailable.  The website you are attempting to access is unavailable during the period of government shutdown. If you encounter agency websites that are available during the government shutdown, please note the following: (1) Information on the website may not be up to date. (2) Transactions submitted via the website might not be processed until appropriations are enacted. (3) The agency may not be able to respond to inquiries until appropriations are enacted.*

Answer (score 2):

Federal Communications Commission: National Broadband Map

http://www.broadbandmap.gov

*Federal Communications Commission
We regret the disruption, but during the Federal Government-wide shutdown, the FCC is limited to performing duties that are immediately necessary for the safety of life or the protection of property. FCC online systems will not be available until further notice.
    FCC Shutdown Plan
    Public Notice on Procedures for Filings
    Notice Regarding Pending Section 214 Applications Due to the Lapse in Appropriations
    Auction 902 Short-Form Application Filing Window Suspended
    Informal Transaction Shot Clocks Suspended During Lapse in Funding
    Postponement of October 2, 2013 E911 Location Accuracy Workshop
If you need to contact the FCC to address an emergency situation, please call: (202) 418-1122 or email: FCCOPCenter@fcc.gov.
Telecommunications companies must continue to use the Network Outage Reporting System (NORS), which will remain available during the shutdown, to file reports of telecommunication service disruptions pursuant to Part 4 of the FCC's rules. NORS allows companies to file Notifications, Initial Reports and Final Reports. The information on service disruptions is essential to maintain and improve the reliability and security of the telecommunications infrastructure.
Vacancy announcements for positions that were open for receipt of applications have been closed and will re-open when the Government is operational.
During this time, the FCC is not accepting any deliveries of supplies, or services that have not been identified as necessary for the safety of life or the protection of property.
The Commission has issued a Public Notice concerning procedures for submissions that would be due to the FCC during the shutdown.*

Answer (score 2):

NASA: Earth Observing System Data and Information System (EOSDIS)

https://earthdata.nasa.gov/tags/web-map-service

*Due to the lapse in federal government funding, the earthdata.nasa.gov website will not be fully supported. Affected systems include: Reverb, ECHO, LANCE, GIBS, URS, Worldview, the Earthdata Collaboration Environment (ECE), and Feedback/support emails.
We sincerely regret the inconvenience.
For more information about available government services, visit USA.gov.*

Answer (score 1):

US Department of Education: School District Demographic System (Map Viewers)

http://nces.ed.gov/surveys/sdds

*Dear Users,
Due to a lapse of appropriations and the partial shutdown of the Federal Government, the systems that host nces.ed.gov have been shut down. Services will be restored as soon as a continuing resolution to provide funding has been enacted.*